# Why is "lazy" a keyword rather than a standard-library type?

Tags: scala, keyword, lazy-evaluation, standard-library

Scala keeps a lot of very useful constructs like Option and Try in its standard library.

Why is **lazy** given special treatment by having its own keyword when languages such as C#, which lacks afore mentioned types, choose to implement it as a library feature?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is true that you could define a lazy value for example like this:

```
object Lazy {  
  def apply[A](init: => A): Lazy[A] = new Lazy[A] {
    private var value = null.asInstanceOf[A]
    @volatile private var initialized = false

    override def toString = 
      if (initialized) value.toString else "<lazy>@" + hashCode.toHexString

    def apply(): A = {
      if (!initialized) this.synchronized {
        if (!initialized) {
          value = init
          initialized = true
        }
      }
      value
    }
  }

  implicit def unwrap[A](l: Lazy[A]): A = l()
}     

trait Lazy[+A] { def apply(): A }
```

Usage:

```
val x = Lazy {
  println("aqui")
  42
}

def test(i: Int) = i * i

test(x)
```

---

On the other hand, having `lazy` as a language provided modifier has the advantage of allowing it to participate in the *uniform access principle*. I tried to look up a blog entry for it, but there isn't any that goes beyond getters and setters. This principle is actually more fundamental. For values, the following are unified: `val`, `lazy val`, `def`, `var`, `object`:

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def bar: A
}

class FooVal[A](val bar: A) extends Foo[A]

class FooLazyVal[A](init: => A) extends Foo[A] {
  lazy val bar: A = init
}

class FooVar[A](var bar: A) extends Foo[A]

class FooProxy[A](peer: Foo[A]) extends Foo[A] {
  def bar: A = peer.bar
}

trait Bar {
  def baz: Int
}

class FooObject extends Foo[Bar] {
  object bar extends Bar {
    val baz = 42
  }
}
```

---

Lazy values were introduced in [Scala 2.6](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#lazy_values). There is a [Lambda the Ultimate comment](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3735#comment-53277) which suggests that the reasoning might have to do with formalising the possibility to have cyclic references:

> Cyclic dependencies require binding with lazy values. Lazy values can also be used to enforce that component initialization occurs in dependency order. Component shutdown order, sadly, must be coded by hand

I do not know why cyclic references could not be *automatically* handled by the compiler; perhaps there were reasons of complexity or performance penality. A [blog post by Iulian Dragos](http://www.iulidragos.org/?p=21) confirms some of these assumptions.

Answer (score 10):

The current lazy implementation uses an int bitmask to track if a field has been initialized, and no other memory overhead. This field is shared between multiple lazy vals (up to 32 lazy vals per field). It would be impossible to implement the feature with a similar memory efficiency as a library feature.

Lazy as a library would probably look roughly like this:

```
class LazyVal[T](f: =>T) {
  @volatile private var initialized = false

  /*
   this does not need to be volatile since there will always be an access to the
   volatile field initialized before this is read.
  */
  private var value:T = _ 
  def apply() = {
    if(!initialized) {
      synchronized {
        if(!initialized) {
          value = f
          initialized = true
        }
      }
    }
    value
  }
}
```

The overhead of this would be an object for the closure f that generates the value, and another object for the LazyVal itself. So it would be substantial for a feature that is used as often as this.

On the CLR you have value types, so the overhead is not as bad if you implement your LazyVal as a struct in C#

However, now that macros are available, it might be a good idea to turn lazy into a library feature or at least allow to customize the lazy initialiation. Many use cases of lazy val do not require thread synchronization, so it is wasteful to have the @volatile/synchronized overhead every time you use lazy val.

Comment: I wonder whether it'd be possible to implement @lazy with macro annotations.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible, but it sure would be useful. There are many different use cases for lazy vals. For example if you just use lazy val to cache a pure function for performance reasons, you do not care if the value might be calculated twice in a race scenario. So you could drop the synchronized.

But if you use the lazy val to manage some external resource, you do care a lot. Obviously the default behavior should still be as safe as possible, but some customization would be very nice...

Comment: Marking a variable as lazy with a keyword has the added benefit of being able to change the behavior an existing statement without really touching the body.
By changing only a keyword other entities are oblivious and the body remains untouched.
In other implementations you will always need to add some Lazy "block" or an implicit definition in the right scope. The Macros remark sounds very interesting, offering different flavors of lazy may be a nice thing to consider. Good thing that @Eugene is here :)

Comment: @EugeneBurmako - That might be interesting to think about—but I don't think it would be a good idea. Annotations are supposed to be ignorable by the compiler, but in a lot of cases where you use `lazy`, ignoring it and making it eager instead would give a completely different result.

Comment: Why are annotations supposed to be ignorable by the compiler?